# What does it really mean to be a child of promise (Gal 4:28)?

Tags: galatians, isaac

Paul in Gal 4:28 refers to his Christian brethren in this way:

> Now we, brethren, as Isaac was are the children of promise.

What does it really mean to be a child of promise?

Comment: Boy you guys are picky. There is a beautiful pearl of great price here, but I have been advised not to answer my own question to quickly if at all. I must say it takes a while to understand the " Rules of Engagement"  for this site. How am I doing for just one week?

Comment: It's not the strict rules that bother me; it's how difficult it is to learn them. It's like some sort of initiation test where figuring out what the rules are is part of the game. This applies to all (most?) Stack Exchange sites. Congratulations for sticking with it.

Comment: @ Ray Butterworth Thank you Ray that means a lot. Kind of like Jesus and Paul teaching on enduring to the end.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the statement in Galatians 4:28, it is important to understand Paul's aim in his epistle to the Galatians. The Galatians were mainly Gentiles who had encountered a situation where they were tending to desert the Gospel of Jesus Christ and believing in a different gospel preached by Jewish teachers who added some requirements in the law of Moses to the Gospel, such as circumcision (Gal 1:6-7).

In chapter 4, Paul quoted pairs of subjects to illustrate the promise of God. He said that Abraham had two sons, Ishmael who was born from Hagar, and Isaac who was born from Sarah. Here are the comparison:

- Hagar was the slave woman, while Sarah was the free woman. (Gal 4:22)
- Ishmael was born according to the fresh (humans), but Isaac was born by the promise (Gen 18:10) God gave to Abraham and Sarah. (Gal 4:23)
- Hagar represented the earthly Jerusalem, whose children (Israelites) were under slavery bound by the law of Moses, whereas Sarah represented the heavenly Jerusalem in which the children are free. (Gal 4:25-26)
- Hagar and Sarah figuratively represented two covenants. Hagar represented the covenant from Mount Sinai (Mosaic Covenant and its binding law - ref Deuteronomy 28) and bears children who are to be slaves (Gal 4:24). She corresponded to the earthly Jerusalem (Gal 4:25). Sarah represented the new covenant and she is the mother of children of promise. She corresponded to the heavenly Jerusalem (Gal 4:26-27).

Therefore in Galatians 4:28, Paul urged the Galatians to choose wisely, not to desert the Gospel of Jesus Christ and put themselves under the law of Moses like slaves. He asked them to be faithful to Jesus and His Gospel, so that they became children of promise like Isaac, free from the law that no one can be declared righteous in God's sight by the works of it (Romans 3:20).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You got the Main point, but please edit your part about Hagar representing earthly Jerusalem. MT. Sinai ( in the allegory) represents sin and the old covenant. It was in the wilderness NOT Jerusalem. Not trying to nitpick though.

Comment: @RHPclass79 - Thanks for the comment. I added the reference Gal 4:24

Comment: Thank you brother.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the snake-crusher was to be the "seed of the woman". Genesis 3:15 says of the snake and the woman:

> And I will make enemies Of you and the woman, And of your offspring
> and her Descendant; He shall bruise you on the head, And you shall
> bruise Him on the heel.”

The narrative in Genesis 4 both *somewhat* equally mention the fathers and mothers when describing the genealogies from Cain to Tubal-Cain and Namaah. But it also mentions Lamech taking two wives. I believe this chapter is outlining very roughly the breakdown in the importance of women in God's promises during those generations.

The end of the chapter returns to Adam and Eve with the birth of Seth and associates him with the return of Yaweh-worship.

At this point, we should expect the following genealogies of Genesis 5 to focus on the matrilineal passing on of the snake-crusher promise.

Especially because Chapter 5 re-states the ideas of Genesis 1:27

> So God created man in His own image, in the image of God He created
> him; male and female He created them.

... and of Genesis 2:24

> "and they shall become one flesh."

... by saying

> On the day when God created man, He made him in the likeness of God. 2
> He created them male and female, and He blessed them and named them
> “mankind” on the day when they were created.

However, what we get instead, is a total exclusion of any explicit mention of women in the Genesis 5 genealogy. To me this indicates that although people began to worship God, they had lost the understanding of the importance women in God's plan.

Both Abraham and Sarah had this faulty view, (that God's promises were passed down through father and son) hence why having a surrogate son through Hagar seemed perfectly fine to them.

However, God had not forgotten that it was to be the seed of the woman to whom the promise was given. In Genesis 17:19 God corrects them:

> No! You and Sarah will have a son. His name will be Isaac, and I will
> make an everlasting promise to him and his descendants.

This was God doing what he did in Genesis 2:24: "and they shall become one flesh." God is bringing together the divine matrilineal promise of Genesis 2 with the human expectation of patrilieage.

However, Ishmael was still a child of promise:

Genesis 17:20

> As for Ishmael, I have heard you; behold, I will bless him, and
> make him fruitful and multiply him exceedingly. He shall father twelve
> princes, and I will make him into a great nation.

And he was still the recipient of God's covenant through Isaac:

Genesis 17:21

> But I will establish My covenant with Isaac, whom Sarah will bear
> to you at this season next year.”

But Isaac was not special within himself. If Ishamel had to access Isaac's promise through circumcision, then Isaac was also required to acknowledge the promise was given not of any inherent quality. He too, had to humble himself to circumcision along with the slaves, servants and foreigners.

Genesis 17:23-27

> 23 Then Abraham took his son Ishmael, and all the slaves who were born
> in his house and all who were bought with his money, every male among
> the men of Abraham’s household, and circumcised the flesh of their
> foreskin on this very same day, as God had said to him. 24 Now Abraham
> was ninety-nine years old when he was circumcised in the flesh of his
> foreskin. 25 And his son Ishmael was thirteen years old when he was
> circumcised in the flesh of his foreskin. 26 On this very same day
> Abraham was circumcised, as well as his son Ishmael. 27 And all the
> men of his household, those who were born in the house or bought with
> money from a foreigner, were circumcised with him.

Comment: where does it say it would be the 'seed of the women' to whom the promise was made? Hagar was a wife G16:3

Comment: That’s exactly right. If there was no matrilineal promise then Ishmael, the firstborn son of Abraham would have been the child of promise. But God specifically says the promise will come through Sarah. We are left to speculate the reason why. I speculate that while men were keeping track of God’s chosen male, God was tracking what was happening with the women, and while Hagar is A woman, she was not THE woman to whom the promise had been passed.